# R: comparing as.character to as.integer or as.numeric

Tags: r

Why does R produce the following results:

```
> as.character('12') > as.integer(2)
[1] FALSE
> as.character('12') < as.integer(2)
[1] TRUE
```

The same happens with `as.numeric` instead of `as.integer`.  My initial instinct is that such a comparison between character and integer should not be allowed or at least should produce an error or a warning.

For a giggle, I tried comparing 12 and 2 as characters, and got similarly perplexing results:

```
> as.character('12')>as.character('2')
[1] FALSE
> as.character('12')<as.character('2')
[1] TRUE
```

What gives?

Thanks,
-R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to `?Comparison`

> Comparison of strings in character vectors is lexicographic within the strings using the collating sequence of the locale in use: see locales. he collating sequence of locales such as en_US is normally different from C (which should use ASCII) and can be surprising. Beware of making any assumptions about the collation order: e.g. in Estonian Z comes between S and T, and collation is not necessarily character-by-character – in Danish aa sorts as a single letter, after z. In Welsh ng may or may not be a single sorting unit: if it is it follows g. Some platforms may not respect the locale and always sort in numerical order of the bytes in an 8-bit locale, or in Unicode code-point order for a UTF-8 locale (and may not sort in the same order for the same language in different character sets). Collation of non-letters (spaces, punctuation signs, hyphens, fractions and so on) is even more problematic.

Answer (score 1):

In a strongly typed programming language, you can't compare different types without explicitly defining how the comparison works.

In R, it's a bit more loose.  R first converts the integer to string, and then does a lexicographical (alphabetical) comparison.  Consider this:

```
> as.character('a') < as.integer(2)
[1] FALSE
> as.character('a') > as.integer(2)
[1] TRUE
```

The only way for comparison of string and integer to work in all cases is if R first converts to character.